# calculate based on constant field

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm fetching a data from the database and with which i need to multiply a entered value and to get an output.
Example,
         Volume = 200 (fetched from database)
         Nos = 10 (requires to Enter manually before generating the report)
         Value = 2000 (Volume * Nos)

How to achieve this in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

Which database you are using? Database has default arithmetic support.

You could do

```
select volume, nos, volume * nos as 'result' from mytable
```

would pick the value and you can just so it on the crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Create a numeric, parameter field named 'Nos'.

Create a formula field, named 'product', enter the following code in its text:

```
{table.volume} * {@Nos}
```

Add formula field to canvas.